# Using Reflection within Html.TextBoxFor()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a dictionary of fields I need to use to map textboxes to database fields. Each key in the dictionary is the same as the model properties that map to the database fields. However I can't figure out how to map them properly. Here's the line of code for the TextBox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    Function(m) m.commFee1,
    New With {.id = Model.CommercialFeesList.Keys(0), .class = "form-control money"})
```

Is there any way I can change the `m.commFee1` in a `for each` loop to map to different fields each time through the loop? For example first time would map to `commFee1`, then `commFee2` etc.? I've tried `m.GetType().GetProperty()` and it didn't like it :)

Comment: If you have a list of field names (strings) that you want to use, it's easier to use `TextBox` rather than `TextBoxFor`.

Comment: But Does TextBox map to model properties?

Comment: Anything maps to model properties as long as the `name` attribute in the resulting `HTML` matches the property name.

Comment: so how would I use TextBox to dynamically map to fields in the model?

Comment: You would call `TextBox` in a loop, each time providing next `name` from your dictionary.

Comment: that worked, thanks!